# Can I use the name of the enum constant in the constructor?

Tags: java, enums

Say I have an enum of `Thing`s with names:

```java
public enum Thing {
    
    THINGA, THINGB, THINGC, THINGD,
    
    THINGE("Thing E"),
    
    ;
    
    public final String name;
    
    private Thing(String pname) {
        
        name = pname;
        //...
        
    }
    
    private Thing() {
        
        // See question
        
    }
    
}
```

Say I want to do the same thing I did with `THINGE` for all my other `Thing`s, except I want the default name to be the same as that of the enum constant itself, e.g.:

```java
private Thing() {
    
    this(/* the name of the constant itself */);
    
}
```

Essentially, I want the implied value of `pname` to be `"THINGA"` for `THINGA`, `"THINGB"` for `THINGB`, `"THINGC"` for `THINGC`, `"THINGD"` for `THINGD`, etc. Using either `toString()` or `name()`, the compiler yells:

`error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called`

Is there any way to avoid this?

Specifically, I include the names for the sake of the user. It feels more natural to look at `"Thing E"` rather than `"THINGE"`, but its much easier for me to program if I can write a method to turn `"THINGA"` into `"Thing A"` and use that in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to give a parameter to the constructor for this, using `name()` and a bit of `String` manipulation should get you there.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Thing value : Thing.values()) {
        System.out.println("value.name = " + value.name);
    }
}

public enum Thing {
    THINGA,
    THINGB,
    THINGC,
    THINGD,
    THINGE;

    public final String name;

    Thing() {
        this.name = name().replace("THING", "Thing ");
    }
}
```

Prints

```
value.name = Thing A
value.name = Thing B
value.name = Thing C
value.name = Thing D
value.name = Thing E
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asked for -- they want their `name` field to default to the enum name().

Answer (score 0):

I believe from your question that you *don't* want to change what `.name()` returns, but introduce another field on your enum values which defaults to `.name()`.

You can do this:

```
public class Comparison
{
    public enum Foo {
        A, B, C("My C");

        private final String myName;

        Foo(String myName) {
            this.myName = myName;
        }

        Foo() {
            myName = this.name();
        }

        public String getMyName() {
            return myName;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(Foo.values()).map(e -> e.getMyName()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and the correct interpretation, but is essentially the same as the other answer with more flavortext.

Comment: The other answer doesn't show how to default some of the enum values to using the standard name. It changes all of them.